# How is unsigned int *ptr treated as prt[i]?

Tags: pointers

```
int *c;
int d,noofentries;

struct A
{
unsigned int *ptr;
int entry;
}a;


a->ptr=memalloc(34,unsigned int);

a->ptr = (unsigned int*) entry


nofoentries = 8 ;
    d =56749;


for(i=0;i<noofentries;i++)
{
c[i] = d; // how is a pointer treated as array ?
}
for(i=0;i<34;i++)
{
a->ptr[i] = c[i]; //segmentation fault occurs
}
```

I require the assignment of  the values populated in `c[i]` to be assigned to `a->ptr[i]`. So that when `a->ptr[i]` deleted  then `c[i]` is also freed.

Kindly help!!

Comment: `c[i]` is equivalent to `*(c + i)`

Comment: you are using a also as pointer first solve that then move forward

Comment: To be precise, the syntax `c[i]` is actually used on a pointer `c`, not an array. If an array name is used, it's converted to a pointer.

Comment: - your code is not compilable. nofentries vs noofentries; entry does not exists... - a->ptr is assgined twice , which one is the good one ? i < 34 => means that noofentries == 34 and c should be allocated accordingling ( c = malloc ( noofentries * sizeof(unsigned int)); ).

Comment: The line `a->ptr = (unsigned int*) entry` does not make sense, you are overwriting a pointer with something that isn't a pointer - this will cause a crush when you try to use the pointer

Answer (score 1):

generally you would not want your `pointer` to be treated as an `array`, rather you would have an `array` and use its `name as pointer` to `refer to any particular member` of the array

for e.g

```
int arr[5];
//the array name 'arr' points to the zeroth element
```

so now you can use `*(arr+ indexNo) = value or arr[indexNo] = value`, to assign a value to a particular element

you would want to use your pointer as an array, when you have assigned an array to it.

for e.g

```
int arr[5];
int *ptr;
```

if you do

```
ptr = arr;
```

you can access `ptr` as you would have accessed arr

as

```
ptr[index]= value;
```

Comment: well i +1 since you're taking time to answer. Just because user3115584 will perhaps never come back to see his answer...

Comment: @philippelhardy thanks, hope he got his answer, even if from somewhere else :P

Answer (score 1):

a pointer to a type is just the same than an array of the type 
*( c + x ) = a
<=>
c[x] = a;

c + x find the right pointer position since it adds x * sizeof(type) to c pointer.

your code compiling under gcc :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A { unsigned int *ptr; int entry; };

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{  
  unsigned int * c;
  unsigned int d;
  int noofentries, i;
  struct A a;

  noofentries=34; 
  c=malloc(noofentries * sizeof(unsigned int));

  d =56749;


  for(i=0;i<noofentries;i++) { c[i] = d; }
  // no need to copy full array c, since ptr is a pointer over it...
  a.ptr = c;
  // warning if above line is not done then allocation of ptr is required:
  // a.ptr = malloc(noofentries * sizeof(unsigned int));
  // and content copy
  // for(i=0;i<noofentries;i++) { a.ptr[i] = c[i]; }

  for(i=0;i<noofentries;i++) { 
    assert( a.ptr[i] == *(c + i) );
    printf("a.ptr[%u]=%u\n",i,*(a.ptr + i));
  }

  free(c);
}
```